# Why do we say "be to blame", not "be to be blamed"?

Tags: grammar, idioms, word-usage

I wonder why "be to blame" is used rather than "be to be blamed"? I've googled it, and what I found is that it is considered as an idiomatic expression.

Comment: I think both are possible in different situations. 1-"be to blame": *It's not our fault. John **is to blame**.* 2-"be to be blamed": *The project is headed toward a disaster. The marketing department **is to be blamed** during next week's stakeholder meeting.*

Comment: @Brandin "John is to blame" does not supply the weasel room that "John is to be blamed" does. In the later case, it might actually be Paul's fault, but John is supposed to take the fall for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a bit of terminology:

*to blame* is an **active infinitive**

*to be blamed* is a **passive infinitive**

Luckily, this issue of "to blame" is known, and was treated by **the greatest grammarian of the English language, Otto Jespersen** (a Dane:-))

He says:

> [**Essentials of English Grammar**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=QD_pVOM4Q3cC&pg=PA336&dq=%22to%20blame%22%20%22to%20be%20blamed%22%20grammar%20passive&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R8cUVaCDApbtoASpxYHIDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22to%20blame%22%20%22to%20be%20blamed%22%20grammar%20passive&f=false)  By Otto Jespersen
>
> 32.2. A related use of the infinitive, which we are therefore entitled to call a secondary, is found in the predicative after the verb be.
>   **In some stock phrases the infinitive, though active in form, has a passive sense**
>
> *The house is to let.*
>
> *He is **to blame**.*
>
> *What’s to pay?*
>
> *The causes were not far to seek.*
>
> *She did what there was to do.*
>
> The **passive infinitive** **may, however, be used**:
>
> *This house is not to be let (always : The house is to be sold or let).*
>
> *He **is to be blamed** for this.*

Jespersen might have used this old grammar for his inspiration:

[**A Comprehensive Grammar, Presenting Some New Views of the Structure of ...**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=KogVAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22to%20blame%22%20%22to%20be%20blamed%22%20grammar%20passive&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bc0UVdLXGtDgoASAwoDoDA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22to%20blame%22%20%22to%20be%20blamed%22%20grammar%20passive&f=false)
**Walton Felch** - **1837**

Thus both alternatives are equivalent and have both a passive sense, more or less.

The same is argued in this other old grammar:

> [**An introduction to English grammar**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JMMDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA106&dq=%22to%20blame%22%20%22to%20be%20blamed%22%20grammar%20passive&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1dAUVceVOvDIsATArIDAAw&ved=0CBsQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22to%20blame%22%20%22to%20be%20blamed%22%20grammar%20passive&f=false) By William Jillard Hort.
>
> In familiar conversation, the **active voice** sometimes seems to be **put**
>   **for** the **passive form** of verbs and participles : as, ... in the act of
>   being forged ; "**they are to blame** ;" that is, " **they are to be blamed**
>   ;" " those books are to bind," to be bound.